# Partition column disappears in result set dataframe Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I tried to split Spark data frame by the timestamp column `update_database_time` and write it into HDFS with defined Avro schema. However, after calling the repartition method  I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.IncompatibleSchemaException: Cannot convert Catalyst type StructType(StructField(random_pk,DecimalType(38,0),true), StructField(random_string,StringType,true), StructField(code,StringType,true), StructField(random_bool,BooleanType,true), StructField(random_int,IntegerType,true), StructField(random_float,DoubleType,true), StructField(random_double,DoubleType,true), StructField(random_enum,StringType,true), StructField(random_date,DateType,true), StructField(random_decimal,DecimalType(4,2),true), StructField(update_database_time_tz,TimestampType,true), StructField(random_money,DecimalType(19,4),true)) to Avro type {"type":"record","name":"TestData","namespace":"DWH","fields":[{"name":"random_pk","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":0}]},{"name":"random_string","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"code","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"random_bool","type":["boolean","null"]},{"name":"random_int","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"random_float","type":["double","null"]},{"name":"random_double","type":["double","null"]},{"name":"random_enum","type":["null",{"type":"enum","name":"enumType","symbols":["VAL_1","VAL_2","VAL_3"]}]},{"name":"random_date","type":["null",{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}]},{"name":"random_decimal","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":4,"scale":2}]},{"name":"update_database_time","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"update_database_time_tz","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},{"name":"random_money","type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":19,"scale":4}]}]}.
```

I assume that the column for partitioning disappears in the result. How can I redefine the operation so it would not happen?

Here is the code I use:

```
    dataDF.write
      .partitionBy("update_database_time")
      .format("avro")
      .option(
        "avroSchema",
        SchemaRegistry.getSchema(
          schemaRegistryConfig.url,
          schemaRegistryConfig.dataSchemaSubject,
          schemaRegistryConfig.dataSchemaVersion))
  .save(s"${hdfsURL}${pathToSave}")
```

Comment: normally the partition column should not be part of the schema to save. in hdfs the save function would create the folder with that information. if you are reading this avro file back in hive it should create the representation of update_database_time  column based on the folder structure.

Comment: the problem is that I need to rename directories with partitioned data. So when I am going to read it back in Hive, the directories name would be without column name: update_database_time_2019-04-12 instead I would have 2019-04-12 for the directory name. Should I use something else instead of partition by for this problem?

Comment: if you have hivesupport enabled you can directly write your DF with partition folder to hive meta store. why go the route of writing to hdfs and then renaming the folder ?

Comment: The problem is that the pipeline is built in such a way that I need to write to HDFS first and only then push the data to Hive metastore

Comment: What is the process that pushes to hive and what is the general file structure of other things that get pushed via that process? There are other (often better) ways to partition the data if you don't care about splitting the data up using those fields. In general, partitionby is used on fields already contained in the data because it creates logically understandable partitions of your data that are easy to navigate on disk. But you don't have to do things that way.

Answer (score 1):

By the exception you have provided, the error seems to stem from incompatible schemas between the fetched AVRO schema and Spark's schema. Taking a quick look, the most worrisome parts are probably these ones:

1. (Possibly catalyst doesn't know how to transform string into enumType)

Spark schema:

```
StructField(random_enum,StringType,true)
```

AVRO schema:

```
{
      "name": "random_enum",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "enum",
          "name": "enumType",
          "symbols": [
            "VAL_1",
            "VAL_2",
            "VAL_3"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

2. (`update_databse_time_tz` appears only once in the dataframe's schema, but twice in the AVRO schema)

Spark schema:

```
StructField(update_database_time_tz,TimestampType,true)
```

AVRO schema:

```
{
      "name": "update_database_time",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "update_database_time_tz",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'd suggest to consolidate schemas first and get rid of that exception before going inside other possible partitioning problems.

EDIT: In regards to number 2 I've missed the face that there are different names in the AVRO schema, which leads to a problem of missing a column `update_database_time` in the Dataframe.

Comment: First of all, I am not sure about random_enum problem, I will look into it. However, update_database_time and update_database_time_tz (tz stands for time zone) are different fields. So the second one appears in data frame as well as in Avro schema, and the 1st one appears only in Avro schema but not in data frame.

Comment: Oh you are completely right, I missed the name difference, sorry :) I'll update the post